# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Pregnant'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am solving a decision tree classification problem. code is below

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier # Import Decision Tree Classifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split # Import train_test_split function
from sklearn import metrics #Import scikit-learn metrics module for accuracy calculation
col_names = ['pregnant', 'glucose', 'bp', 'skin', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'pedigree', 'age', 'label']
# load dataset
pima = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv", header=None, names=col_names)
#split dataset in features and target variable
feature_cols = ['pregnant', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'age','glucose','bp','pedigree']
X = pima[feature_cols] # Features
y = pima.label # Target variable
# Split dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1) # 70% training and 30% test
# Create Decision Tree classifer object
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
#Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

And Preview of dataset: 
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvQHi.png)

I am getting an error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Pregnant'
```

Please help me solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line to read the data with headers from csv file:

From:

```
pima = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv", header=None, names=col_names)
```

to

```
pima = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv") # This will import the data file with the header names from the csv, which you can change later if required.
```

Or manually remove the top row using this code:

```
pima = pima.iloc[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first non header line of your dataset contains what looks to be a duplicate header line. Thus the first value of X is "Pregnant" and not a float as you require.

You could either filter out non float values or fix your dataset.